# Insert multiple child records with different dates after insert of parent record

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm working on functionality to create Activity__c records in bulk when a PlanSchedule__c record is created. I am able to insert X number of Activity__c records based on a calculated value derived from subtracting the start date from the end date then dividing by the specified frequency, which is either 180 or 365 days. What I cannot figure out is how to specify the Scheduled_Date__c for each inserted Activity__c record. The first Activity__c record should have a Scheduled_Date__c equal to the First_Scheduled_Date__c specified in the PlanSchedule__c record, which is achieved in the existing code. Each subsequent Activity__c record should have a Scheduled_Date__c equal the prior record's Scheduled_Date__c plus 180 or 365 days.

For example:

- Activity1: Scheduled_Date__c = First_Scheduled_Date__c
- Activity2: Scheduled_Date__c = Activity1's Scheduled_Date__c +
  Frequency__c
- Activity3: Scheduled_Date__c = Activity2's
  Scheduled_Date__c + Frequency__c

How can the code below be modified to achieve this?

The trigger calls the below class "after insert":

```
public class PlanScheduleCreateActivities {

public static void schedule(List<PlanSchedule__c> schedules) {

    List<Activity__c> activities = new List<Activity__c>();

    // For each schedule processed by the trigger, add a new  
    // activity record for the specified activity type. 

    for (PlanSchedule__c newSchedule : schedules) {
        if(newSchedule.Activity__c != null) {
            for(Integer i = 0; i < newSchedule.Quantity_Calculated__c; i++) {
                activities.add(new Activity__c(
                    Clinical_Study__c = newSchedule.Clinical_Study__c,
                    Activity__c = newSchedule.Activity__c,
                    Vendor__c = newSchedule.Vendor__c,
                    Schedule__c = newSchedule.Id,
                    Assigned_to__c = newSchedule.Assigned_to__c,
                    Scheduled_Date__c =newSchedule.First_Scheduled_Date__c)
                );
            }
        }
    }

    insert activities;        
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyler,

you can simply add `frequency * (i+1)` to the first schedule date for each subsequent activity. something like this

```
          int frequency = 180;// or 365

          for(Integer i = 0; i < newSchedule.Quantity_Calculated__c; i++) {
                activities.add(new Activity__c(
                    Clinical_Study__c = newSchedule.Clinical_Study__c,
                    Activity__c = newSchedule.Activity__c,
                    Vendor__c = newSchedule.Vendor__c,
                    Schedule__c = newSchedule.Id,
                    Assigned_to__c = newSchedule.Assigned_to__c,
                    Scheduled_Date__c = newSchedule.First_Scheduled_Date__c)  + (frequency * i)
                );
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work with `integer frequency = integer.valueOf(newSchedule.Frequency_Calculated__c);` and `Scheduled_Date__c = newSchedule.First_Scheduled_Date__c + (frequency * i) `